# Sending extra variables with a jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I have a bunch of divs that when they are clicked I want to update some data that is associated with it. I have a click event registered with the div but I can't figure out how to pass the data into the click event handler along with it. I've looked at quite a few other similar SO questions but haven't found a working solution yet.

I want to basically be able to click a box and pass the number along with it:

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var container = document.getElementById('container');

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){    
    var checkbox = document.createElement('div');
    checkbox.setAttribute('class','checkBtn');

    var save = function(){
        console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
    $(checkbox).click(function(){
        save();
    });
    container.appendChild(checkbox);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1qrvxe1j/

Comment: what data you want to pass

Comment: I want to pass a dictionary of data from our server, a string, and the checkbox instance.

Comment: your code will always log "four".

Comment: I'm confused by the fiddle, exactly what is that trying to show?

Comment: With each button I want to log a different number "one", "two", "three" etc...

Comment: sorry, I started from someone elses fiddle and I guess I got the wrong share link. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use closures... try his code.

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var container = document.getElementById('container');

var save = function (arg1) {
    console.log(arg1);
}

var clickEvent = function (i) {
    return function () {
        save(numbers[i]);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){    
    var checkbox = document.createElement('div');
    checkbox.setAttribute('class','checkBtn');

    $(checkbox).click(clickEvent(i));

    container.appendChild(checkbox);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this works. But I have a hard time following why I have to do it this way.

Comment: When you do a for loop and declare a function inside this for loop accessing the var i, all functions declared inside this for loop will access the last value of var i. When you use a closure defined in `clickEvent`, each function will receive a copy of the var i in the moment that clickEvent is called. If i wasn`t clear, please, follow this link https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: The @Ninsly code should work too.

Comment: I read the duplicate answer explanations and I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JQuery [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through the array.

```
$.each(numbers, function(index, num) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('div');
    checkbox.setAttribute('class','checkBtn');

    $(checkbox).click(function(){
        console.log(num);
    });
    container.appendChild(checkbox);
});
```